# How do you send simple JSON objects through to ASP.NET without creating a new Class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, json

Sending objects to ASP.NET from JSON works fine if you have a class built that matches the JSON object, but all I need to do is send a single integer.

```
var request = { "int": jQuery('select#propSelect').val() }

            jQuery.ajax({
                url: '/Property/getPropByID',
                type: 'POST',
                data: JSON.stringify(request),
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                success: on_request_success,
                error: on_request_error
            });
```

Does anybody know how to do this?

Once it gets to the server I try to print out what has been passed and it displays nothing.

```
    public void getPropByID(string objects)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("JSON> "+ objects);
        //return js.Serialize(db.Properties.Find(id));
    }
```

Comment: So it doesn't display `JSON>` it mustn't be calling that function then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you need to do is send an int, then do this:

```
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: '/Property/getPropByID',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {'myint':$('select#propSelect').val()},
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: on_request_success,
            error: on_request_error
        });
```

And on the web service side:

```
public void getPropByID(int myint)
{

}
```

**Note**: I believe the parameter name on your web service must match the parameter name on the client side.

Comment: Thanks, I actually didnt realise that the parameter names had to match!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var request = { objects: jQuery('select#propSelect').val() }
```

Comment: Doesn't that fail because the value must have the same name as the property on the web service side?

Comment: @JaredPar Yeah he have name of property "objects" on server side